# How is $z=4xy$ a hyperbolic paraboloid?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Show that the following quadric surface represents a hyperbolic paraboloid: $$z=4xy$$

From my knowledge, I know the hyperbolic paraboloid has a general equation $\frac {x^2}{a^2} - \frac {y^2}{b^2} = cz$ but I can’t seem to solve this.

Comment: Investigate $x=u+v,y=u-v$.

Answer (score 3):

$z=4xy$ is the same as $z=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$, so after the (linear) change of variables $x'=x+y$, $y'=x-y$, you get $x'^2-y'^2=z$, which has the form of a hyperbolic paraboloid. In other words, the surface $z=4xy$ is the image of the hyperbolic paraboloid  $x^2-y^2=z$ after applying a linear transformation to it.

Comment: This is a very useful technique in general: there are many shape description equations that are very elegant when we restrain them to be oriented in a certain way or have a certain location as a center, but get considerably nastier when we need them to be generic.  Using linear changes of variables will allow you to use these shapes when the shapes aren't as nicely placed as we'd like them to be.

Comment: I was wondering the technique used to get z = (x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2 from z= 4xy